# Sending an E-Mail via Google Mail

Tags: c#, .net, mono, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send an E-Mail via Gmail using MailKit. This is my code:

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
    //...
}
```

But no matter what I try I always get the following exception:

> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed.

I already tried to enable "unsafe apps" in my Google account, but that did not help. So far I could not find any working example that shows how to send mail via Gmail.

**Edit:**
I just tried running the Code on WIndows (using .NET), and it worked perfectly. The E-Mail got sent right away. Only when I run it on Linux/OSX using Mono, it does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail?

Comment: the error is giving you all the hints.. `authentication` where are you passing the username and password for gmail account.. also there are `TONS of working examples on how to do this using standard .net's smtp class.. try going some google searches on how to send email to gmail using smtp

Comment: @MethodMan: The username and password are provided AFTER calling the connect method. Have you ever used MailKit?  As for the .NET Smtp class: I tried four different examples found here on Stack Overflow. NONE of them worked. They also produce a similar authentification exception.

Comment: @Sylverac: How can it be a duplicate if it uses a completely different framework (MailKit, not .NET SMTP classes)?

Comment: Perhaps this helps.  http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient_Connect_1.htm, client.Connect ("smtp.gmail.com", 465, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

Comment: @Jose: No, it still throws "The authentication or decryption has failed".

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer!
Adding the following line of code to the beginning of my program solved it:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Now MailKit sends the E-Mails as it should. So does the .NET/Mono SMTP class.

Comment: Great !! Please, this solution works with "unsafe apps" or without?  Thanks. :-)